# Running 'mysqldump' on an Azure Runbook

Tags: python, mysql, azure, powershell, azure-devops

so I wrote a python script that runs 'mysqldump' to generate a dump which is then stored as a backup. Locally, the script works without a hitch, but the end goal is to be able to add it as a Runbook to an Azure Automation Account, so it runs once a day.

The issue currently, is that the Azure environment does not have a MySQL module, as MySQL is not a Windows product, so I cannot run any MySQL commands (I get the error '`#The system cannot find the specified file`'), including 'mysqldump'. I have tried using different python connectors, but they all obviously need a version of mysql to be reachable. I have also been looking into redoing everything as a Powershell Runbook instead, as there seem to be some more options than for python (e.g. [SimplySQL](https://github.com/mithrandyr/SimplySql/wiki)). I can add the SimplySQL module and I can call it from the Runbook, which is a step forward, but as far as I could see, there is no option or support for 'mysqldump'. This means, that I would need to somehow recreate the 'mysqldump' command by redoing it's functionality with simple queries, which are supported.

This, of course, is less than optimal and very error prone, so if anyone has better options, useful tips or tools it would be a great help!

---

Not sure if it's somehow helpful, but here is my python script.

```
    import logging
    import os
    from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient
    from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT
    from datetime import datetime
    from dotenv import load_dotenv
    import importlib.util
    import sys
    
    def generateDump():
    
        load_dotenv()
    
        process, process_output = runMySqlDumpCommand()
    
        if (process.returncode != 0):
            logging.error('ERROR CODE: ' + str(process.returncode))
            return
        else:
            generateAndUploadBlob(process_output)
    
    def runMySqlDumpCommand():
        command_args = [
            "mysqldump",
            "-P",
            f"{os.getenv('PORT')}",
            "-h", 
            f"{os.getenv('HOST')}",
            "-u",
            f"{os.getenv('DUMP_USER')}",
            f"-p{os.getenv('DUMP_PASSWORD')}",
            f"{os.getenv('DATABASE')}"
        ]
    
        #The system cannot find the specified file
        process = Popen(command_args, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT, universal_newlines=True)
        process_output = process.communicate()[0]
        process.wait()
    
        return process, process_output
    
    def generateAndUploadBlob(process_output):
        timestamp = datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%Y_%H:%M:%S")
        filename = os.getenv('DATABASE') + "_" + timestamp + ".sql"
        blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(os.getenv('DUMP_STORAGE_CONNECTION'))
        blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container=os.getenv('DUMP_CONTAINER_NAME'), blob=filename)
    
        blob_client.upload_blob(process_output)

if __name__== "__main__":
    generateDump()
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you are correct the data operation which you are trying to perform is not possible with mysql since it is not a first party MS product. But you are perform the same using Azure SQL.

The only option right now I can think to solve the problem you are facing with automation is by using the [SimplySQL module](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/SimplySql/1.8.0) to get a runbook connecting and querying the database. The connection properties are very simple and allow connections to multiple database types, including MySQL. You can install and get quick stat of SimplySQL using the following command.

```
Install-Module -Name SimplySql -RequiredVersion 1.6.2
Get-Module SimplySQL
```

After that using the **Invoke-SqlQuery** you can pass along the MySQL query to the connection you open with the Open-MySQLConnection cmdlet.

Note that to back up an existing MySQL database on the local on-premises server or in a virtual machine, you can consider [dump and restore using mysqldump cmd tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/mysql/concepts-migrate-dump-restore#dump-and-restore-using-mysqldump-utility).

But other that this I can't think of any way to achieve the result. As a workaround you can use the SQL Server with PowerShell runbook to achieve the backup operation which you want to perform. For that check this [Azure Automation: Export Azure SQL Database to Blob Storage in a BACPAC file](https://www.sqlshack.com/azure-automation-export-azure-sql-database-to-blob-storage-in-a-bacpac-file/) document for more information.